# ROC50 score - how is it calculated?

Tags: svm, roc

I have never found a good explanation of what the ROC50 score is and how it is calculated.

To take an example definition found on the net:

> The ROC50 score is the area under the ROC curve, up to the first 50 false positives

So if I understand correctly, you look at how many correct positive classifications you have, until you get the first fifty wrong ones.

But this makes the ROC50 score dependent on which positive classifications you look at first- if they are true or false.

What ordering does one use? Does one look at the objects most confidently classified as positive first?

I.e. for an SVM-classified list of objects you begin with the object with the highest score from the decision function and work your way downwards until you get to fifty false positives?

If so, is it correct to say that the ROC50 score gives you information about how well the most confidently classified objects are classified?

Comment: Since AUC measures have been discredited as inconsistent for comparing classifiers I would advise you don't use these methods anymore.  (of course that doesn't invalidate the questions, since we need to understand these methods for their historical context and to understand old research).

Comment: @Corone - If there's general scientific agreement that the AUC is a poor indicator, it's news to me, and in health care research I see Concordance or the C-statistic used very frequently.  Can you back up your statement for me?

Comment: Mostly work by D. Hand:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2564.  Specifically applied to healthcare this is probably most relevant: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.3859/abstract

Comment: I think the gist of the problem is that AUC attempts to be agnostic to misclassification cost, but in doing so it effectively averages over an aribitrary prior distribution for costs.  The distribution changes as you change classifier, so the AUC of two curves are not measuring "the same thing".

Comment: That said "general scientific agreement" may admittedly not have occured yet (but that doesn't make it right :-) ).  I possibly could have left out "have been discredited" and just said "have been shown to be", but I can't edit the comment now